# Run own shell scripts and orchestrate them with Foreman

Tags: theforeman

Is there any way I can run my own scripts in Foreman? For example to take some specific actions  or to check everything is right after some update.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your own shell scripts during provisioning time by creating custom "Provisioning Templates" under Hosts -> Provisioning Templates. However, that would only run during the initial provisioning process. If you want to be able to run "scripts" to check the state of the machine after provisioning, you should really look into using Puppet, Chef, etc. Puppet is the one that is "native" to TheForeman, but I believe you can work with other configuration management software as well.

Templates: http://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/index.html#4.4.3ProvisioningTemplates